# How can the browser handle encrypted data without HTTPS?

Tags: video, https, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I have a use case where the back end serves encrypted video files with a `Content-type: video/mp4` HTTP header. Normally, the browser (any browser) would start streaming the video file in it's built-in player, but since the data is encrypted, it doesn't know how to handle it.

The way the encryption is done is kind of like HTTPS. The server sends the front end a public key, the front end generates a symmetrical key with the public key and both the server and front end use it to encrypt/decrypt stuff.

I know that if I was using HTTPS, it would work, as an automatic process would occur between the server and browser. So I guess my question is *how do I get the browser to display an encrypted video without using HTTPS?*

Answer (score 0):

You must either use a video player that natively knows how to decrypt that format (contact the vendor of the back end), or put a piece of middleware in to decrypt the format (contact the vendor of the back end).  In both cases, you'll need the key as well.

Or log into the back end to change its settings (guess who you should contact).

Alternately, read the manual for the back end.